# How to display parent(s) methods/variables in Outline?

Tags: java, eclipse

The Eclipse's *Outline View* only displays the active class's methods/variables.

Is it possible to also display the parent class's (and maybe the parent's parent, and so on...) methods/variables in the *Outline View*?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not in the *Outline View*  but in the *Type Hierarchy View*:

With the cursor in your class name, click `F4` (or select "*Open Type Hierarchy*" in the context menu). You'll see the *Type Hierarchy View*, where you can click "*Show all inherited members*".

Answer (score 22):

For completeness: pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> in an editor opens the outline view as a popup. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> again adds all inherited methods to the popup.

Comment: gold! thanks for this tip, it even says so in grey letters at the bottom of the pop-up, i just never looked that far down :-)