# Have IDE jump to overridden toString() method implementation?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am using eclipse neon. I am dealing with an extensive class hierarchy, like:

```
class AbstractBase { ...

class ImplA extends AbstractBase { ...

class ImplAB extends ImplA { ...
```

Assume I have ImplAB opened in my eclipse. I *know* that some of its ancestors does @Override toString() - and I would like to jump to that source code.

In other words: given a class X that *inherits* some method `foo()`, but doesn't override `foo()` itself - is there a *quick* way to jump to that version of `foo()` that "applies" to X?

To be more precise: assume that the *cursor* sits somewhere in class X, and within class X itself there is *no* call to that method.

A workaround would be to quickly type `foo()` somewhere in the source and then press F3 on that - but then I have to **undo** that change (and yes, this might be a problem when you have auto-save enabled).

And while we are at it: in case this is not possible in eclipse, can somebody say if IntelliJ has this feature?

Comment: Does  `open declaration` not work?

Comment: workaround: call `toString()` on an object of `ImplA` and the ctrl+click on that method call to go to the implementation. (Might be another key combination on Eclipse)

Comment: @ScaryWombat Open declaration / F3 works by opening the "thing" you have currently selected. But I dont have anything to click/press f3 on. Guess I have to update my question.

Comment: @Tom Yes, workaround. But i would prefer a solution over a *workaround*. Especially a workaround that makes me modify the source code and forces me to remember to undo that change.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Only insofar as that tool shows the inheritance hierarchy, and allows a manual search in one place.

Comment: which could also be quite extensive

Comment: About your edit @GhostCat: [IntelliJ does support this via the `Structure` tool window (Alt+F7) if you click the "Inherited" button in its toolbar](http://imgur.com/5Lc5QeP.png). If you double-click the list item, it navigates to its implementation.

Comment: How about F4 (type hierarchy)?

Comment: plus one to not delete - most useful question all week

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: You can double-tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to view inherited members in a simple popup.

---

You can use the [type hierarchy window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040974/how-to-display-parents-methods-variables-in-outline) (Shortcut: <kbd>F4</kbd>) while the cursor is in the class name.
Next to `Child`, click on the `Show all inherited members` icon:

[image]

---

If you want a somewhat quicker way to do this (which includes a search bar), simply double-tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and you can start typing:

[image]

---

As you edited your question, this also exists in IntelliJ via the [Structure tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structure-tool-window-file-structure-popup.html) (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: @GhostCat I'm not quite sure that exists. However, you _could_ start typing while that section has focus and it would navigate to that method name as it is a normal list. The one downside is that (in Eclipse) it seems to display _all_ parent occurrences of this method (e.g. `Object` and `Base`). Edit: I added another way of doing this which may be more "shortcut-esque".

Comment: What you can do in IntelliJ is hit `Ctrl+F12` (File Structure popup) twice and then type `toString` or whatever method you're looking for, maybe that is quicker.

Comment: @xander I didn't know about that - that is a nice feature! It seems the same as Ctrl+O Ctrl+O, maybe the IDEs are more similar than I thought :P

Comment: Excellent. CTRL O two times ... I would suggest that you edit your answer a bit to make that more clear. Like moving that sentence to the begin of the answer.